# Django filter/exclude against list of objects

Tags: django

I'm having a model `Animal` and list of Animal objects

```
A1 = [a1, a2, a3]
```

Now I am making a Django query

```
A2 = Animal.objects.filter(some__filters)
```

Now I want to exclude A1 from A2

```
A3 = A2.exclude(A1) // Wouldn't simply work.
```

I know I have to do something like this

```
A3 = A2.exclude(id__in=[a.id for a in A1])
```

Should there be a shorter version of that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `filter()` and `exclude()` are translated to SQL queries. Your plain list of elements can't be translated to SQL, so you need to do the translation to the list of ids yourself.

Comment: If you have a queryset for A1, you can use difference.

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1. Using your particular scenario:

- Retrieve your list as a queryset:
  `a1 = Animal.objects.filter(pk__in=[a1.pk, a2.pk, a3.pk])`
- Get your queryset:
  `a2 = Animal.objects.filter(some__filters)`
- Get the difference between your querysets:
  `a1.difference(a2)`

## Option 2. Difference

This option assumes that a1 is a queryset.

- Get the difference between a1 and a2:
  `a1.difference(a2)` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#difference)